# Converting String to Datetime and finding maximum in Datatable C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to convert a DataTable datacolumn which is of type String to DateTime and finally I want to find maximum date from the datatable .
Is it possible to do this thing in c#?

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact`. You can use LINQ:

```
var allDates = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("DateColumn")));
DateTime maximumDate = allDates.Max();
```

Basically this is the same as this loop:

```
DateTime maxDate = DateTime.MinValue;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("DateColumn"));
    if (dateTime > maxDate) maxDate = dateTime;
}
```

Comment: I am getting an exception "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." by using above code.

Comment: @IshanTrikha: Then you need to provide more informations. Provide sample strings and your culture/country.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with [DataTable.Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataTable dt = GetTable();
    DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("Date= MAX(Date)");

   if (dr!=null)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(dr[0]["Date"]);
   }    
}

static DataTable GetTable()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));

    table.Rows.Add(1, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString());
    table.Rows.Add(2, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString());
    table.Rows.Add(3, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).ToString());
    table.Rows.Add(4, DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString());

    return table;
}
```

Comment: This won't work since OP wants to order by the date and not by the string.